# How to send multiple string variable using MultipartEntity from Android

Tags: java, android, multipartentity

I am trying to send images and values of Latitude and Longitude using MultipartEntity.Values of Latitude and Longitude are stored in a separate variable named plat and plong. I am able to sends images to the server but not both Latitude and Longitude. At the Server end only the Latitude ends up inserted into database. Bellow is the code that I am using to send the file and strings to the server. Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong?

```
 private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        if (bitmaps[0] == null)
            return null;
        setProgress(0);

        Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert
                                                                    // Bitmap
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // ByteArrayOutputStream
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert
                                                                            // ByteArrayOutputStream
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // ByteArrayInputStream

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.example.com/index.php"); // server

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            reqEntity.addPart("long",String.valueOf(plong));
            reqEntity.addPart("lat",String.valueOf(plat));


            Log.e(TAG, "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (response != null)
                    Log.i(TAG, "response "
                            + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            } finally {

            }
        } finally {

        }

        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Following is the addPart() method in MultipartEntity class.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

public void addPart(final String key, final String value) {
    writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
    try {
        out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +key+"\"\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n".getBytes());
        out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
        out.write(value.getBytes());
        out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    } catch (final IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this,

```
reqEntity.addPart("long",new StringBody(plong));
reqEntity.addPart("lat",new StringBody(plat));
// or plong.toString() and plat.toString() depending on your plong and plat datatype
//and then add to httppost
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

to send the lattitude and longitude.

However you can check this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity), good exapmles are here and can be really helpful to understand

Answer (score 0):

Set the entity after the adding the request part and also add  `new StringBody()` to the `String.valueOf()`  :

Do this , may this help you :-

```
 MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
 reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
 System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
 reqEntity.addPart("long",new StringBody(String.valueOf(plong)));
 reqEntity.addPart("lat",new StringBody(String.valueOf(plat)));
 httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting error on StringBody asking me to make an StringBody class or change to a different string method.

Comment: You have to download the jar "httpmime-4.03"

Comment: Download the jar through this link:- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime411jar.htm

Comment: Thanks Harsh, for your help. But I am getting another error now. this time it is asking me to modify the addPart method in MultipartEntity class. Its is  telling to chage the addPart(string, string) to addPart(string, stringBody).Did that but then asking me to modify the content of the method as well. Don't have a clue what to change now. I have edited my main post to show the addPart() residing inside MultipartEntity class. So requiring help in this as well.

Comment: Why you are overiding addPart() method

Answer (score 0):

yes @Harsh was right...your are setting the entity....before adding the part data to the multipartentity....

change your code ...

```
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        reqEntity.addPart("long",String.valueOf(plong));
        reqEntity.addPart("lat",String.valueOf(plat));
```

to this...

```
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
        //httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);//remove this line and place after setting all part values

        reqEntity.addPart("long",new StringBody(plong));
        reqEntity.addPart("lat",new StringBody(plat));
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity); //place it here....
```

Comment: I did that as well but not getting any improvement.

Comment: have to seen my updated code? if yes...then will you plz..show me your web-service file .... first make sure ..did that service receive the lat and long value... as i think from android side..everything is fine...so make sure is these values are received by webservice..? show me your service file if possible?